# Show that for any odd natural $n$, and a natural $k$ such that $1 \leq k \leq n − 1$ $k^n + (n − k)^n \equiv 0 \pmod n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I was given this question and I am completely confused how to go about it. Show that for any odd natural n, and a natural k such that $1  \leq k \leq n − 1$

$$k^n + (n − k)^n \equiv 0 \pmod n$$

I tried to search the textbook and online for a similar problem but could not find one.

Comment: $2^3+(3-2)*3 = 11$ which is not $0$ mod ($3$).

Comment: Did you copy the problem correctly?  clearly $(n-k)n\equiv 0$ mod($n$) so you could delete that whole term.  You are then left with $k^n$ on the left and if $(k,n)=1$ that term will never be $0$ mod($n$).

Comment: @lulu yes sorry i edited it

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can use $(a+b)^n=a^n+\dbinom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b+\cdots+\dbinom{n}{n-1}ab^{n-1}+b^n$ will have symmetric structure since $n$ is odd and the terms where I put explicitly binomial notations are zero. That is

$$
(a+b)^n=x+y \pmod n
$$
where $a^n=x \pmod n$ and $y=b^n \pmod n$. Now take $a=n-k$ and $b=k$. By the way the claim is true for $k=0$ and $k=n$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(n-k)^n\equiv (-k)^n\equiv -k^n \pmod{n}$.

If congruences are not yet familiar, imagine expanding $(n-k)^n$ using the binomial theorem. We will get a bunch of terms divisible by $n$, followed by $(-k)^n$, which is $-k^n$ since $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\eqalign{
& k^n+(n-k)^n = \cr
= {} & k^n+(-)^n(k-n)^n \\
= {} & k^n-(k-n)^n \qquad \text{because $n$ is odd} \\
= {} & (k-k+n)(k^{n-1}+k^{n-2}n+\cdots +kn^{n-2}+n^{n-1}) \\
= {} & n(k^{n-1}+k^{n-2}n+\cdots +kn^{n-2}+n^{n-1})
}
$$